# Why jqGrid can't convert serialized datetime json?

Tags: json, jqgrid, datetime-format, jqgrid-asp.net

[image]

Hi, 
Everythink perfect without datetime on jqGrid :S How to fix this convertion problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your ColModel

```
{name: 'colNmae', index: 'ColName', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "m/d/Y h:i A" }}
```

Or this

```
{name: 'colNmae', index: 'ColName', sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', datefmt: 'd-M-Y'},
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the formatter to date in your colModel and jqGrid will automatically detect the Microsoft date format.

The srcformat is not needed to be set, but newformat can be.

Try this:

```
colModel : [
...
{name:'Mydate', ...formatter: 'date', formatoptions:{newformat 'm/d/Y'}, ...},
...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

These column properties worked for me

```
formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "ISO8601Long" }
```